# The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly, A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, compiler-errors

The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll". A required privilege is not held by the client SkyOnTheWay.Toolkit.Test 
=> This occurred all of sudden. I was compiling OK. After changing some code and tried to build again, all of sudden it fails with above error. Cannot go further.

I updated all nudget packages, updated visual studio 2019's updates available, restarted computer several times.
Nothing works. Those answers out there internet are similar but all are little different and nothing worked.

I use VS 2019 and was building Universal Windows' app.

I further test with new project to confirm it's not code issue.

1. I added new project - Unit Test App (Universal Windows)
   Then, compiled. It's OK.
2. I installed Win2D.uwp nudget. (1.24.0)
   Then, compiled. It causes the Error. Nothing further can be done due to the error.
   ** I have used Win2D for years and no problem. Now all of sudden this causes and big issue.
   Also, the error does not occur on class library.

I heard other people complaining the same issue; No change at all, all of sudden 'CodeTaskFactory' error occurs!

**Anyone found a workaround or fix?**

Comment: What exactly is your code trying to accomplish, i assume it deals with file manipulation or dealing with something on the C drive? If so, consider perhaps changing the read/write permissions of the target files/folder (if that is what it is doing)